# debugging problems im getting from react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

Hello guys so i started learning React native and i already created an todo App with no problems but now when i moved to my second project i started getting a lot of problems while using custom fonts and Navigation !
the error message is : Unable to resolve module react-navigion from D:\Programing\Second project\gamezone\routes\homeStack.js: react-navigion could not be found within the project.

and when i try to watchman watches as they say i get this error :  The term 'watchman' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program .....

can any of u guys help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your library name is misspelled.

Check your ***homeStack.js*** file.

Instead of `react-navigation` you wrote `react-navigion`.

Also make sure you have it installed by running `npm install react-navigation`.

But I also would clear the cache and delete node_modules folder and then run npm install again to make sure your project is clean.

To clear the cache:

`npm cache clean --force`

To remove node_modules folder quickly:

`rm -r node_modules`